# How to fetch new data from an activity that was launched through an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

This is a bit of a complicated problem.  In the `ViewHolder` of my RecyclerView's custom adapter, I've implemented an `onClickListener` and through the `onClick`, I'm passing an intent that fires up `EditItemActivity` with text and recyclerview list item position as extras.  In the `EditItemActivity`, I have a TextView that has the text that was passed from an intent and a "Save Changes" button.  That text belonged to a specific list item in my Recyclerview list.  After I change the text, I want the app to go back to the main screen with the list and have that specific item updated with the new text.

So far, here what I was able to successfully implement:

1. `EditItemActivity` launches whenever a list item is clicked.
2. When the activity launches, it's textview has the same text as the list-item whose onClick launched the activity.

What I want to add:

- When I change the text in the `EditItemActivity` and click the "Save Changes" button, it updates the text of that same list item.

Here is my implementation.  This is `ViewHolder` in my adapter that houses the `onClick`:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView todoView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            todoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_do_display);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", todoView.getText());
            intent.putExtra("position", getAdapterPosition());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

And this was my attempt that updating the text of that list item:

```
public class EditItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_item);

        final ToDoData toDoData = new ToDoData(this);
        final ToDoAdapter toDoAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(this);

        final EditText editToDo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_todo_item);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_changes);
        final String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
        final String position = getIntent().getExtras().getString("position");
        editToDo.setText(text);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(editToDo.getText().toString() != text){
                    toDoData.setToDo(editToDo.getText().toString());
                    toDoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ADDING CODE PER REQUEST**

Code for the class that has the listview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<ToDoData> toDoList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ToDoAdapter toDoAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(toDoList, this);

        final EditText toDoInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_todo);
        Button toDoAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_item);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RecyclerView toDoDisplay = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.toDoDisplayRecyclerView);
        toDoDisplay.setAdapter(toDoAdapter);
        toDoDisplay.setHasFixedSize(true);
        toDoDisplay.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        toDoAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ToDoData newToDoData = new ToDoData(MainActivity.this);
                newToDoData.setToDo(toDoInput.getText().toString());
                toDoList.add(newToDoData);
                toDoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                toDoInput.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code for the adapter:

```
public class ToDoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ToDoData> toDoList;
    private Context context;

    public ToDoAdapter(List<ToDoData> todoList, Context context) {
        this.toDoList = todoList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ToDoAdapter(Context context){}

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView todoView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            todoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_do_display);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", todoView.getText());
            intent.putExtra("position", getAdapterPosition());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.to_do_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
        ToDoData todoPosition = toDoList.get(position);

        holder.todoView.setText(todoPosition.getToDo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (toDoList == null) ? 0 : toDoList.size();
    }
}
```

ToDoData.class

```
public class ToDoData implements Serializable{
    private String toDoString;

    public ToDoData(String todoString){
        this.toDoString = todoString;
    }

    public ToDoData(Context context){}

    public String getToDo() {
        return toDoString;
    }

    public void setToDo(String toDoString) {
        this.toDoString = toDoString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the activity that has the listview and the code for adapter that populates the view ?

Comment: Check the edit... @SumitJha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your ToDoData class implement Serializable.

   ```
   public class ToDoData implements Serializable{}
   ```
2. Now, pass the `List<ToDoData>` into the EditItemActivity along with the `positon` and `data` through Intent as:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditItemActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("data", todoView.getText());
   intent.putExtra("position", getAdapterPosition());
   //along with data and position, we are passing the list as well.
   intent.putExtra("LIST", (Serializable) toDoList); //this 'list' is your toDoList that you pass to the adapter (and gets populated into the view)
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. Now, inside your EditItemActivity,

   Receive the list from the intent as:

   ```
   Intent i = getIntent();
   list = (List<ToDoData>) i.getSerializableExtra("LIST");
   ```

   And set the listener for button click as,

   ```
   toDoAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           // set the new input of user from toDoInput into the list 
           list.set(position, *object_of_ToDoData_with_updated_user_input*);
           startActivity(new Intent(EditItemActiviy.this, MainActivity.class));

       }
   });
   ```
4. Inside MainActivity,

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       toDoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   }
   ```

Comment: Where to I place number 2?

Comment: Inside MainActivity.  (we need to pass the list from MainActivity to EditItemActivity)

Comment: Where is myIntent coming from?

Comment: I have edited code to make it clear. Do let me know if you need more help.

Comment: The problem is that in number 2, MainActivity has no access to `toDoView` or `getAdapterPosition`.  I'm already passing this intent through my adapter.  Don't you think I should keep it there?

Comment: Ya, I meant inside Adapter code only. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: There are problems with #3 as well.  The get method in `list.get(position).set(editToDo.getText().toString());` is expecting an int when `position` a String.

Comment: To summarize, the solution is to pass the list as well to EditItemActivity. Now, once the save button is pressed (Inside EditItemActivity), the list (passed through intent) is modified at that position based on new user input and MainActivity is started.

So, ``list.get(position).set(editToDo.getText().toString());`` means to simply update (set new value) at the required position.

Comment: I understand but even when I place position in `Integer.parseInt(position)`, now the set method turns red.  I agree with your idea but what point is there in code that doesn't work?

Comment: set method turns red because your list is the List of ToDoData, and you cannot pass an integer to the set method (You need to pass object of ToDoData). Can you please share your ToDoData class. I will help you then.

Comment: and what if `MainActivity` is killed while you are in `EditItemActivity` ? You should use `startActivityForResult` and `setResult` to pass changes back to `MainActivity`.

Comment: Okay its up there.  Btw Idk who downvoted you but I just upvoted you.  I'd appreciate it if you could upvote my post as well.

Comment: Upvoted. As @RadekJ mentioned, while you open EditItemActivity to edit the item, you should start this as startActivityForResult. Anyway that's fine for now.
And if this solves your need, could you please mark it as accepted ? Thanks in advance :)